# Is it necessary to verify iss claim in a jwt if the jwk_urls are configured?

Tags: jwt

I am using auth0, and I have a setup a custom domain. As a result, depending on how I login, I can have multiple `iss` claims, for example :

- https://example.auth0.com
- https://auth.example.com

So I have to configure all my backend services to accept both these `iss` claims. I was wondering, if I always check the jwt signature with the jwks url (either from auth0 domain or mine, it will lead to the same document), is it ok to just skip `iss` verification, as I can verify that the issuer is the one hosting my jwks_url page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Suppose your service somehow receives a token from a bad actor, for example with an `iss` claim of `https://badactor.auth0.com`, then your service retrieves the jwks from `https://auth.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json` and successfully validates the signature. What could have gone wrong?

- Auth0 used the same signing keys for different tenants. [Apparently it does not](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets).
- The bad actor somehow obtained the private signing keys of your Auth0 tenant. If they did that, they could have just as easily set the `iss` claim to one your service expects as well. There are no JWT validation steps that can protect against compromised signing keys.
- The bad actor somehow intercepted your service's request to `https://auth.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json` and returned its own keys.

  - Your service must not have verified the certificate on the TLS connection to auth.example.com.
  - Or the bad actor was able to forge a certificate as well. You can't protect against that.

So, a valid signature based on a key from *a trusted source* is sufficient to validate the issuer of the JWT.

Comment: `Auth0 used the same signing keys for different tenants` I didn't even consider this possibility, if it was the case honestly I think it would be a valid reason to just stop using auth0 :D 

Your answer confirms what I suspected, thanks for the reply!